# Training Faster R-CNN with multiple objects in an image

Tags: deep-learning

I want to train Faster R-CNN network with my own images to detect faces. I have checked quite a few Github libraries, but this is the example of the training file I always find:

```
/data/imgs/img_001.jpg,837,346,981,456,cow
/data/imgs/img_002.jpg,215,312,279,391,cat
```

But I can't find an example how to train with images containing couple objects. Should it be:

```
1)  /data/imgs/img_001.jpg,837,346,981,456,cow,215,312,279,391,cow
```

or

```
2)  /data/imgs/img_001.jpg,837,346,981,456,cow
    /data/imgs/img_001.jpg,215,312,279,391,cow
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I just could not help myself but [quote FarCry3 here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKMMCPeiQoc): "The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results." 
(Note that this is purely in an entertaining context, and not meant to insult you in any way; I would not take the time to answer your question if I didn't think it worthwile)

In your second example, you would feed the *exact same input data*, but require the network to learn two different outcomes. But, as you already noted, it is not very common for many of the libraries to support multiple labels per image.

Oftentimes, this is purely done for the sake of simplicity, as it requires you to change your metrics, to accomodate for multiple outputs: Instead of having one-hot encoded targets, you now could have multiple "targets".

This is even more challenging in the task of object detection (and not object classification, as described before), since you now have to decide how you represent your targets. 
If it is possible at all, I would personally restrict myself to labeling one class per image, or have a look at another image library that does support that, since the effort of rewriting that much code is probably not worth the minute improvement in the results.